# How to remove the unnecessary html after appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var split = $('.split-locations').text().split('\n');
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
   $('.split-locations').append("<pre>"+split[i]+"</pre>");
}

<div class="split-location">
Singapore
USA
Aussie
</div>
```

On profile, the user type with enter for each address, but the problem is when it is saved, the addresses would be displayed on the webpage as:

```
Singapore USA Aussie
<pre>Singapore</pre>
<pre>USA</pre>
<pre>Aussie</pre>
```

I am not sure why the text (Singapore USA Aussie) is still there. Only wanted to display:

```
<pre>Singapore</pre>
<pre>USA</pre>
<pre>Aussie</pre>
```

How to remove the first line before `<pre>` bunch? Or how to replace text with pre bunch?

**Update**

One more thing: how to print first array outside loop because need to display first one outside loop and then put the rest of array inside accordion?
Here the code is: for you to understand what I am trying to do. see the comment.

```
 var location = $('.split-locations');
    var split = $('.split-locations').text().split('\n');
    location.empty();
    //need to print first location

    location.append('<div class="accordion-location">');
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      //print remaining location after minus first location
       location.append("<pre>"+split[i]+"</pre>");
    }
    location.append('</div>');
    });
```

Comment: split-location or split-locations ?

Comment: split-locations - sorry for typo

Comment: Singapore USA Aussie is still there because you are appending the stored variable split one so just empty before you append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to clear out the location:**

```
var split = $('.split-locations').text().split('\n');
$('.split-locations').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
   $('.split-locations').append("<pre>"+split[i]+"</pre>");
}
```

Update:

```
var $el = $('<div class="accordion-location"></div>');
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
   $el.append("<pre>"+split[i]+"</pre>");
}
location.append($el);
```

Comment: thanks and one more how to print first array outside loop? Also how to count the remaining arrays in loop after first array? Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by outside the loop. Do you mean outside the split-location?

Comment: yes outside split-location. I wanted to have one array print out first then after minus the first location, the rest of locations will be printed inside the accordion div. i post the update code so u see what i mean

Answer (score 2):

You need to empty the container element before appending the `pre` nodes. Try this.

```
var split = $('.split-locations').text().split('\n');
$('.split-locations').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
   $('.split-locations').append("<pre>"+split[i]+"</pre>");
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderOMara -- thanks and one more how to print first array outside loop? Also how to count the remaining arrays in loop after first array?

Comment: You can access the first array element with `split[0]`, you can do something like `$("SELECTOR").text(split[0])` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: thanks! I got it down already before I saw your answer. thanks a lot.